# How to return error messages on custom content-types in Spring?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have some `@RestController` with `Spring`. I use the query parameter `?format=` to control the returned content type (this is a spring build-in feature).

Problem: if content-type is not json/xml, but eg text or `csv`, spring will try to convert the error response returned into `csv`. Which of course fails and therefore I'm not returning eg an `AuthenticationException`, but a `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException`.

?format=json:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2017-11-15T11:00:07.079+0000",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Bad credentials",
    "path": "..."
}
```

?format=xml:

```
<Map>
    <timestamp>2017-11-15T11:00:21.590+0000</timestamp>
    <status>401</status>
    <error>Unauthorized</error>
    <message>Bad credentials</message>
    <path>...</path>
</Map>
```

?format=csv: (I offer some endpoints that directly create text csv files):

```
Response could not be created: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
```

Question: how can I tell spring to format any error responses as eg plain text, incase the format parameter is not json/xml?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the spring controller advice annotation and exception handlers. Thus catching all manner of error and responding in a general way.

```
@ControllerAdvice
class YourControllerAdviceClass {
    @ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason="Exception occured")
    @ExceptionHandler({ Exception.class })
    public YourReturnType handleAllException() {
        return YourReturnType;
    }
}
```

for more info you could read this article to give you more options with regards to your error handling and response possibilities.

http://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

Comment: But this only catches the `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException` after spring tried to convert the original exception to `csv`. The execption response with fields `timestamp, status, error, message, path` is generated by spring, somewhere else.